# Proper use of GetLongPathName function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to use the `GetLongPathName` function exactly the same way I'm using the `GetShortPathName`:

1. Call the function with `NULL` as output param for getting the size to allocate.
2. Allocate the string dynamically.
3. Call the function again with the allocated string.

GetShortPathName MSDN page says:

*Passing* `NULL` *for* `lpszShortPath` *and zero for* `cchBuffer` *will always return the required buffer size for a specified* `lpszLongPath`.

**That note is not exists** in `GetLongPathName` function so I'm afraid to use the function that way.

So, what is the proper use for that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `GetLongPathName` with either an empty or a `NULL` buffer and it will answer with the required buffer length.

In other words, you can pass `NULL` for the `lpszLongPath` argument and `0` for `cchBuffer`.

Comment: You probably still want to widen the buffer on error as the documentation suggests in order to handle races though. `MAX_PATH` seems like a reasonable initial guess.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `NULL` as the `lpszLongPath` argument and `cchBuffer = 0`.

Comment: @Leandro Caniglia - Thanks! one last question. Is the answer the same for GetFullPathName (another function from the same family)?

Comment: You can but if you are going to call twice, you may as well pass a MAX_PATH length buffer on the first call and so mostly avoid a second call.

Comment: While not explicitly documented, that the `lpszLongPath` may be null, the *FileAPI.h* header uses the `_Out_writes_to_opt_` SAL annotation (see [Annotating Function Parameters and Return Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916382.aspx) for additional information). The annotation includes `_opt_` which designates a pointer parameter that may be null.

Comment: @Ofer The main difference between the two functions is that the file must exist for `GetLongPathName` to work.